# SQLite DatabaseHelper class is not creating database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I've been working on a simple Chronometer app that stores lap times in a Database. I've created a Database Helper class. When I try to insert the data from my activity  I get an error saying that there is no such table created. I have removed some of the code from the activity here for simplicity(the code for buttons, etc)
At first i though there is a problem with using constants but I have created the table without any of them and I get the same error.
UPDATE: I think my onCreate is never called in the DBHelper.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.andrei.gymhelp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "SQLMessage";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StoredResults.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static DatabaseHelper mDatabaseInstance = null;
private Context mContext;


public static DatabaseHelper newInstance(Context context){
    //first check to see if the database helper
    //member data is null
    //create a new one if it is null

    if (mDatabaseInstance == null){
        mDatabaseInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    //either way we have to always return an instance of
    //our database class each time this method is called
    return mDatabaseInstance;
}



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
}
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LAPS = "create table results_table "
        + "("
        + "_id" + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "timestamp" + " text not null, "
        + "laps" + " text not null, "
        + ")";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   try{
       db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LAPS);
       Log.d(TAG, "TABLE WAS CREATED ");
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       Log.d(TAG, " Error create database " + e.getMessage());
   }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.LAPS_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

 }
}
```

TimerActivity.java

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private TextView timer;
private Button btnStart;
private Button btnLap;
private Button btnStop;
private Button btnSave;
private TextView laps;
private int lapsCounter = 1;
private ScrollView scrollLaps;
private boolean saved = false;
private String savedLaps = "";
private static final String TAG = "MESSAGE";
Date dateAndTime = new Date();
private String sequenceTimestamp;

private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private Chronometer mainChronometer;
private Thread threadChrono;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_timer);


    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mDatabase  = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mainChronometer != null) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = getString(R.string.chrono_not_stopped);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }else{
                if (!saved) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "LAPS = " + savedLaps);
                    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    saved = true;

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = getString(R.string.saved_toast);
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    sequenceTimestamp = (String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy", dateAndTime.getTime());

                    saveResultsToDatabase(sequenceTimestamp, savedLaps);
                    Log.v(TAG, sequenceTimestamp);

                    } else {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = getString(R.string.alreadysaved_toast);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void updateTimer(final String time){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer.setText(time);
        }
    });
}
public void saveResultsToDatabase(String timestamp,String stringOfLaps) {
    //if (mDatabase != null) {
        //prepare the transaction information that will be saved to the database
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constants.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
        values.put(Constants.COLUMN_LAPS, stringOfLaps);

        try {


            Log.i(TAG,"SAVE RESULTS WAS CALLED");
            mDatabase.insert(Constants.LAPS_TABLE, null, values);

            mDatabase.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    //}
}

}
```

Error

```
01-08 22:09:09.081 10656-10656/com.example.andrei.gymhelp E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
01-08 22:09:09.083 10656-10656/com.example.andrei.gymhelp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting timestamp=10:09:04 08-01-2018 laps=Lap 1: 
00:00:00:786|Lap 2: 00:00:01:283|Lap 3: 00:00:01:756|Lap 5: 00:00:02:177|
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: results_table (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO results_table(timestamp,laps) VALUES (?,?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1725)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1593)
     at com.example.andrei.gymhelp.TimerActivity.saveResultsToDatabase(TimerActivity.java:186)
     at com.example.andrei.gymhelp.TimerActivity$4.onClick(TimerActivity.java:150)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: I suggest that you do not catch the SQLException in your database helper class. This will help you immediately find the syntax error in your code. If you want to manage unforeseen errors and display appropriate messages to the user, the try...catch statements are more appropriate in the UI code.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database does in fact exist. However the table **results_table** is not in the database.

The table is not being created due to a syntax error. The **laps** column, the last defined, has a trailing comma, so another column definition is expected.

To fix this change `+ "laps" + " text not null, "` to `+ "laps" + " text not null "` (i.e. remove the comma at the end.).

The `onCreate` method will only be called if the database doesn't exist, before rerunning the app you should either a) delete the App's data or b) uninstall the App.

Comment: Thank you, I have spotted the mistake as well after 3 hours :(